# De-duplicate rows in CSV with Python while adding a row value

Tags: python, csv

I've got a csv file that I read and write in Python. It looks like this

```
location, lat, lon, people
paris, 34, 41, 12
london, 22, 43, 14
paris, 34, 41, 16
```

I'd like to transform it by keeping the unique values while adding the `people` together. It would look like this after transformation:

```
location, lat, lon, people
paris, 34, 41, 28
london, 22, 43, 14
```

From what I gather, using a dictionary is the way to go, but I haven't managed to crack the logic of this just yet.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you have any code that could be posted in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly refer to the `csv` [built-in library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Then:

- Read your document line by line.
- Use the values of every row to populate a class *city* using the columns name as attributes.
- Write the list of objects you have created in a new csv file.

Comment: Thanks @mabe02. I'm getting as far as populating the class when iterating over every row of the CSV, but not further (I haven't got round classes just yet).

Comment: @basbabybel was this answer useful?